# Showing num keyboard for currency on mobile devices with validation

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input, currency

So I've read through a bunch of other similar questions but I'm at a loss as to what I can do.

I have an input box that takes a currency so I'd assume clients would put `$2.50` in. I'd also like to have the num keyboard display when a user clicks on it. However if I use `type="number"` it allows the entry of `$` but the event no longer has that content in it and hence I cannot validate it.

I thought about using the keypress function, and although there isn't a value I could convert the code but this seems overkill.

I've tried putting `novalidate` on the form but it doesn't seem to do anything. I've also seen an attribute `event.target.willValidate` that I thought could be doing something as it's always true but `no validate` doesn't seem to affect it.

I've also seen one solution that flicks it between `text` and `number` to show the correct keyboard but turn off the validation. This also seems a bad work around.

Anything else I could try?